# Jolt add key value to children

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am using `NiFi Jolt` Processor to transform some JSON data.

I need to create array of objects. I can get all objects from assets, but I want to add each date in parent to my object.

I have the following input JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2022/01/09",
    "assets": [
      {
        "value": 1,
        "percentage": 0.1
      },
      {
        "value": 2,
        "percentage": 0.2
      }
    ],
    "liablities": []
  },
  {
    "date": "2022/01/08",
    "assets": [
      {
        "value": 3,
        "percentage": 0.3
      },
      {
        "value": 4,
        "percentage": 0.4
      }
    ],
    "liablities": []
  }
]
```

And this my expected output:

```json
[
  {
    "value" : 1,
    "percentage" : 0.1,
    "date" : "2022/01/09"
  },
  {
    "value" : 2,
    "percentage" : 0.2,
    "date" : "2022/01/09"
  },
  {
    "value" : 3,
    "percentage" : 0.3,
    "date" : "2022/01/08"
 },
 {
   "value" : 4,
   "percentage" : 0.4,
   "date" : "2022/01/08"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use this Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "assets": {
          "*": "[].@(2,date)"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "[&2]",
          "$": "[&2].date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative approach as applying two successive **shift** transformations in order to walk through the indexes of `assets` arrays, and pruning the generated keys `0`,`1` within the second step such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "assets": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3[&1].&",
            "@(2,date)": "&3[&1].date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The Demo has been prepared on https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ :

[image]

Comment: Very cool solution, thank you